# Googles samplesoftkeyboard

Tags: android, android-keypad

I just load Android Sample project "Samplesoftkeyboard"

I edited symbols.xml into my custom like pattern

now the problem is

if user pressed some combination of keys i need to display some Character

How can i do that ?

EDIT:
if user type some combinations to key i need to show some different characters eg: if user press *45@ then i need to change as A when user type @ symbol in that keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file in `xml` with the name `popup.xml` and insert following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:keyWidth="10%p" 
        android:horizontalGap="0px"
    android:verticalGap="5%p"
    android:keyHeight="@dimen/key_height">
</Keyboard>
```

In your keyboard layout file (something like `qwerty.xml`) you have to edit the key the following way to get a popup with a definded selection of suggestions:

```
<Key android:codes="117" android:keyLabel="u"
        android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popup"
        android:popupCharacters="ü"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay .. I am asking if user type some combinations to key i need to show some different characters eg: if user press *45 then i need to change as A